# The internal hyperlink defined in jupyter-notebook is not working

Tags: jupyter-notebook

While creating Table of Contents in jupyter-notebook using `<html>`
I created hyperlinks linking to internal notebook cells, But clicking them does not take me to the desired cells.

Example:
The markup in the table of content is like:

```
    <ol>
        <li><a href="#understanding">Understanding the Data</a></li>
        <li><a href="#reading_file">Reading the file</a></li>
        <li><a href="#adding_columns">Adding Columns</a></li>
        <li><a href="#general">General Analysis</a></li>
    </ol>
```

Whereas the code in the Cells linked by above hyperlinks are as follows:

```
<h2> Understanding the Data </h2>
<h2> Reading the file </h2>
```

... and so on

Answer (score 1):

Like to share the solution to my problem as follows:

a. The hyperlink's href attribute should be preceded by hash'#' and exactly match the name of the linking cell( case insensitive) 
with dash( no underscore ) replacing the spaces.

e.g.

```
<ol>
        <li><a href="#understanding-the-data">Understanding the Data</a></li>
        <li><a href="#reading-the-file">Reading the file</a></li>
        <li><a href="#adding-columns">Adding Columns</a></li>
        <li><a href="#general-analysis">General Analysis</a></li>
    </ol>
```

b. Whereas on the cells I am linking to, there should not be any space between opening and closing tags that are encompassing the name.
e.g.

```
<h2>Understanding the Data</h2>
<h2>Reading the file</h2>
<h2>Adding Columns</h2
<h2>General Analysis</h2>
```

Note that now there is no space between html tags and the name defined within.